# how to give marquee to a hyperlink in repeater control

Tags: asp.net

I want to show some scrolling(marquee) link in my Website form to
display data I am using repeater control.but when i am trying to give
marquee to the repeater it doesn't give me output How I give marquee
Please help. My code:

```
<div id="calendar1">
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CBMIAConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT Event FROM [Home_EventLink]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

    <table id="Head_Meeting">
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size: large; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-transform: capitalize; color: white;">&nbsp&nbsp<i class="fas fa-calendar-alt" style="font-size: 25px; color: white"></i>&nbsp  Upcoming Meetings</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <div id="Meeting_Event" padding-left="5px" padding-right="5px">

        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" class="hyperlink" Text='<%# Eval("Event") %>' href="home.aspx" runat="server" /><br />

            </ItemTemplate>
            <SeparatorTemplate>
                <hr />
            </SeparatorTemplate>

        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
THIS MAY HELP
<marquee id="MyMovingText" style="width: 80%" scrollamount="5" onmouseover="stop();" onmouseout="start();" runat="server" direction="left">
                <asp:datalist RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ID="rptbreaknews" runat="server">
                            <ItemTemplate>

                                            <a class="readmore"  target="_blank" href='<%#"details.aspx?Id="+Eval("Id") %>'>
                                                <h3><asp:Label ID="lbltext" Text='<%#Eval("NewNewsTitle") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label></h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            </a>

                        </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:datalist>
            </marquee>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `marquee` like this. And do not use `class` and `href` within an aspnet Control but use the correct properties like `CssClass` and `NavigateUrl`

```
<marquee id="MyMovingText" direction="left" scrollamount="10">

    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>

            <div class="scroll-item">
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" CssClass="hyperlink" Text='<%# Eval("Event") %>'
                  NavigateUrl="/home.aspx" runat="server" />
            </div>

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

</marquee>

<style>
    .scroll-item {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 50px;
    }
</style>
```